# Force client to use specific Lan port to connect to server

Tags: router, switch

Newbie question:

I have a NAS box connected to my gigabit ethernet Switch, the same NAS box is also connected to a 100mbps router switch to connect to the internet.

The client users are wirelessly connected to the router switch for their internet connection.

But they are also connected to the gigabit ethernet switch to the NAS box to have high speed acces to the NAS.

When the client connects to the NAS box he connects trough the wifi (slower connection). Is there a way to force a connection to the NAS box trough their gigabit NIC?

I realise it is vage and broad but any hint in the right direction is appreciated.

THX!

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? As it stands it appears to be more of a client issue and not a network issue, which wouldn't really fit this site.

Answer (score 0):

If the LAN is completely flat (aka, all the same subnet on the switch AND the private side of the router, normally a 255.255.255.0 /24 Class-C network), then (if Windows) in the TCP/IP v4 properties of the wireless nic, adjust the advanced properties where the automatic interface metric checkbox is... then set it to something high like 200.

This should force the wireless nic to be less preferred to the gigabit nic... when the gigabit nic is plugged in. When it is not plugged in, the wireless nic will be the only choice and the packets will flow in that direction until the gigabit nic is plugged back in.